# AJAX Login Form: Undefined PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, authentication

I am having problems with an ajax login form. I am getting an a error from ajax saying that my username and password variables in my login_check.php file are undefined. Yet, when I initialize the variables to blank, the error goes away. The problem is, when I initialize the variables to blank, even if I put the right information into the login box, it will not let me log in. I am sure the problem is minor, but I just can't see it. I just need the PHP and AJAX to work together and then I'm done. Thanks in advance.

login_check.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'login.class.php';
$error = NULL;
$success = FALSE;

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$login = new Login();
//Connect to MYSQL Database server
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL Database.");
$result = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connect) or die("Could not connect to MYSQL table.");

//Clean Data to prevent malicous injections
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($_POST['username']))));
$password = $login -> encrypt(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($_POST['pass'])))));

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'") or die("Query to database failed.");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
if ($numrows > 0) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $success = TRUE;
    echo json_encode(array("success" => "Login successful."));

} else {

    $success = FALSE;
    echo $error = 'Invalid username or password!';
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "Invalid username or password! (PHP response)"));

}
?>
```

JQuery file

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $('.username').val();
        var password = $('.password').val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "includes/login_check.php",
            data : "Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password,
            dataType : 'json',
            cache : false,
            success : function(data) {
                if(data.error) {
                    $('.login div.error').show().html(data.error);

                } else {
                    $('.login div.success').show().html(data.success);
                }

                //return false;

            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
            },
            beforeSend : function() {
                $(".load").html("Loading...");
            }
        });

    });
```

By the way, the error from AJAX is:

**error parsererror: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character**

Thank you again friends.

Comment: $success should be true or false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems:

This:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

should be this:

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
```

Those keys have to match the parms you specified here:

```
data : "Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password,
```

...and even that should be changed to:

```
data : {"Username":username,"Password":password},
```

This line is producing invalid JSON:

```
echo $error = 'Invalid username or password!';
```

I think you meant to code just this?

```
$error = 'Invalid username or password!';
```

**EDIT #1:**

Also this line needs to be the very first thing in the PHP code:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: 'username' and 'pass' is what I named the name attributes in the HTML form

Comment: @Sephiroth, they all have to match in the form, the ajax call and the login_check.php.

Comment: @Sephiroth, see my edit. Very important. Also, others found other errors. Check their answers. Lots o' problems in this code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what's the purpose of doing this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
```

when later on in your script, you do this?

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($_POST['username']))));
$password = $login -> encrypt(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags(stripcslashes(trim($_POST['pass'])))));
```

You are *fetching the POST data twice*. Instead, use the `$username` and `$password`. Don't forget to check if they exist in the POST array. Using data that isn't existing may yield unexpected results.

---

Then also, this part of the code presents an error. You are echoing invalid JSON.

```
echo $error = 'Invalid username or password!';
echo json_encode(array("error" => "Invalid username or password! (PHP response)"));
```

looks like this in the returned data:

```
Invalid username or password!{"error":"Invalid username or password! (PHP response)"}
```

remove the first echo

---

The POST array corresponds to the query string/data you passed in the AJAX call. Therefore:

```
data : "Username=" + username + "&Password=" + password,
```

is:

```
$username = $_POST['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];
```

Answer (score 1):

delete or comment out this line:

```
    echo $error = 'Invalid username or password!';
```

And add `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0):

Username != username and Password != pass :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a copy of what is being returned(should be able to to with debugging the error) then paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ and it should help track down the JSON syntax error.